# Linux gui debugger for assembly debugging (i.e without sources)

Tags: linux, debugging

Gdb and ddd are not very handy for my purposes, IdaPro + gdbserver are not working for some reason. I remember i used one decent linux debugger and it's name remembered me about some windows debugger. I would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball is in the shop, so I can't tell you what debugger you were using. However, a good choice for asm-only debugging (read: reverse engineering) is [radare2](http://www.radare.org/y/).